# Is there a circuit that will take power from two sources and would use the second only if the first is down?

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design, power-electronics

I'm looking for a specific circuit that would be connected to 2 power supplies. However, unless the first one fails e.g. power outage, the second one will not be used. I'm not familiar with the name of such a circuit to begin with. Would there be off-the-shelf products designed for this purpose? If not, how can I design one?

Comment: This question has been asked many times on here. Try searching. You might want to look up the TPS2115A though.

Comment: So, they're called Auto-switching Power Multiplexers/Mux! Makes a lot of sense!!

Comment: Depending on the system used it can be as simple as using two diodes